# Power Series Expansion

Tags: calculus, power-series

I was flicking through a book on perturbation methods and saw a simple question asking the reader to expand the following expression for $f$ in a power series (up to the first 2 terms):

$f = (1 + \epsilon \,x)^{1/\epsilon}$, where $\epsilon$ is a small parameter. I'm sure this is very simple, but I wasn't certain about the best way to approach this. A quick look at mathematica tells me the solution is $e^x - \frac{1}{2} (e^x x^2) \,\epsilon + ...$. How would I go about getting this answer - and more importantly, how would I systematically find series expansions for problems similar to this one?